# Shorter notation for columns in pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, calculated-columns

Take a random DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(3, 2), columns=['a', 'b'])
```

Pandas allows defining new columns in two ways:

```
df['c'] = df.a + df.b
df['c'] = df['a'] + df['b']
```

As the DataFrame name gets longer, this notation becomes less readable.

And then there's the `query` function:

```
df.query('a > b')
```

It returns the slices of the `df` that match the condition.

Is there a way to run something like [`DataFrame.query()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) but for operations on the frame?

Answer (score 3):

Function [`DataFrame.eval()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.eval.html) does exactly this:

```
df.eval('c = a + b')
```

And warning-free assignment:

```
df.eval('c = a + b', inplace=True)
```

More generally, [`pandas.eval()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.eval.html):

> The following arithmetic operations are supported: +, -, *, /, **, %,
>   // (python engine only) along with the following boolean operations: |
>   (or), & (and), and ~ (not). Additionally, the 'pandas' parser allows
>   the use of and, or, and not with the same semantics as the
>   corresponding bitwise operators.

Pandas docs say that `eval` supports only [Python expression statements](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#expression-statements) (e.g., `a == b`), but pandas silently supports `abs(a - b)` and maybe other statements. The rest throw an error. For example:

```
df.eval('del(a)')
```

returns `NotImplementedError: 'Delete' nodes are not implemented`.

Comment: My prior criticism was incorrect... You can pass a `\n` delimited string of formulas.  Also, the `float` issue I highlighted was specific to my use of `abs`.  You should include such something like `c = a + b\nd = c ** 2`.  Note that you can refer to columns created prior in the same string.

Comment: I'd also include some output.  For me, there is something satisfying about seeing the output.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way using `assign` and `add`:

```
df.assign(c=df.a.add(df.b))

          a         b         c
0  0.086468  0.978044  1.064512
1  0.270727  0.789762  1.060489
2  0.150097  0.662430  0.812527
```

Note: The assign creates a copy of your dataframe, therefore you aren't distorting the original data. You'll need to reassign to a different variable or back to df.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the dataframe named `my_obnoxiously_long_dataframe_name`

```
np.random.seed([3,1415])
my_obnoxiously_long_dataframe_name = pd.DataFrame(
    np.random.randint(10, size=(10, 10)),
    columns=list('ABCDEFGHIJ')
)

my_obnoxiously_long_dataframe_name

   A  B  C  D  E  F  G  H  I  J
0  0  2  7  3  8  7  0  6  8  6
1  0  2  0  4  9  7  3  2  4  3
2  3  6  7  7  4  5  3  7  5  9
3  8  7  6  4  7  6  2  6  6  5
4  2  8  7  5  8  4  7  6  1  5
5  2  8  2  4  7  6  9  4  2  4
6  6  3  8  3  9  8  0  4  3  0
7  4  1  5  8  6  0  8  7  4  6
8  3  5  8  5  1  5  1  4  3  9
9  5  5  7  0  3  2  5  8  8  9
```

---

If you want cleaner code, create a temp variable name that's smaller

```
d_ = my_obnoxiously_long_dataframe_name

d_['K'] = abs(d_.J - d_.D)
d_['L'] = d_.A + d_.B

del d_

my_obnoxiously_long_dataframe_name

   A  B  C  D  E  F  G  H  I  J  K   L
0  0  2  7  3  8  7  0  6  8  6  3   2
1  0  2  0  4  9  7  3  2  4  3  1   2
2  3  6  7  7  4  5  3  7  5  9  2   9
3  8  7  6  4  7  6  2  6  6  5  1  15
4  2  8  7  5  8  4  7  6  1  5  0  10
5  2  8  2  4  7  6  9  4  2  4  0  10
6  6  3  8  3  9  8  0  4  3  0  3   9
7  4  1  5  8  6  0  8  7  4  6  2   5
8  3  5  8  5  1  5  1  4  3  9  4   8
9  5  5  7  0  3  2  5  8  8  9  9  10
```

Comment: You used `abs` in `eval()` in your unedited answer. Do you have the list of other undocumented statements supported by `pandas.eval()`?

Comment: @AntonTarasenko I don't have a list handy.  But I know that things like `max`, `min`, `log`, and others do work... note the `engine` parameter defaults to `numexpr`  *`engine : string or None, default ‘numexpr’, {‘python’, ‘numexpr’}`*  You can [**find lots more information here**](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/numexpr)

Comment: Thanks! Now I think the pandas package code must contain the implemented (and not implemented) nodes.